# How to unlock DLink router

Tags: router, upgrade, updates, firmware, adsl

I have a DLink ADSL router DSL-2740U with firmware version ME_1.03 
I downloaded the new firmware img file from
https://dlinkmea.com/index.php/product/details?det=NmFNY0ZsYnAvN3BYZlA0a0d2blliQT09
I tried to upgrade the firmware via the Maintenance tab >> Firmware Update then I clicked on Browse button then selected the .img file and clicked on Update Firmware button nothing happened on my screen but the router restarted and it took a minute or so then I logged back again to find that it still has the old version I tried the update several times but it still shows the old version
I realized that the router is locked by my ISP
Is there a way to unlock it? so I can update its firmware
The router has no DD-WRT suitable flash installation file

Comment: It appears the ISP owns / manages the box, so you will need to ask them to upgrade the firmware.

Comment: @John I know that and they won't help me that is why I am asking for a way to unlock it so I can update it myself.

Comment: If they can't help nor you can't upgrade it, you're trying to circumvent restriction and that makes it off-topic.

Comment: I suggest you leave the box as is. It would not be a good idea for you / us to change the box as that is how they provide you service.